# Windows "dir" command has different results if run from prompt or from inside JVM

Tags: java, windows, prompt

A small software that I must mantain, to avoid piracy or similar hacks, uses this trick: since it's free to use for 30 days, it creates an encrypted file in a special folder at the first run, and then at every startup it compares the creation date of that file with the today's date to see if the evaluation has expired.

That said, the software was developed for Java 1.6 which didn't have anything to get that information from a file, so without using any 3rd party library my colleagues decided to use this code

```
Process process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c dir /Tc path/filename");
```

to get as a String the output of the "dir" command (which would contain the creation date of the file), and then perform the comparison.

Lately I noticed that this didn't seem to work anymore, and when I explored this part of code, I made a discovery that I can't understand (on my development PC).
Simply put, I added a printout of the output of process above, and it looked like this (it's italian, but I think you can understand that the file was found):

```
line:  Il volume nell'unità C è Windows
line:  Numero di serie del volume: 4480-D4E2
line:
line:  Directory di C:\path
line:
line: 19/05/2017  12:23               886 filename
```

while, the same command ran directly from windows prompt returned no file with that name.

Since this file was deleted and re-created over and over on my PC, I tried this on other computers, and the results were the same. The command run from Java always finds this "ghost" file, even if the file has been deleted from the disk. I noticed that the creation date of this file is always the date when I first launch the software and the file is created.

**So, the question is, how come that the same command ran from java code and ran from windows prompt gets different results? Am I missing something?**

I should probably add that our software doesn't use a jre regularly installed on windows, but it's shipped with jre 1.7.0_65 as a subfolder of the installation folder, and uses it to run.

**EDIT:** the special folder under which the file is created is Windows' System32 folder.

Comment: What is the current path when running from JVM? Try using absolute path.

Comment: Is your 'path' in/under `\Program Files` or `\Program Files (x86)` ?

Comment: The current path, when running from JVM, is the installation folder (which is not where the special file is saved). I'm unable to try using an absolute path at the moment though.
The software is installed under x86 program folder, but the special folder isn't. 
Oh well, I'll be specific. The file is saved under Windows System32 folder. I'll update the question with this piece of info.